# Two conditions in one if statement does the second matter if the first is false?

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

Okay, so I have this piece of code tested and I found there isn't any exception thrown out.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] list = {1,2};
    if (list.length>2 && list[3] == 2){
        System.out.println(list[1]);
    }
}
```

Does the statement here

```
if (list.length>2 && list[3] == 2)
```

mean that if the first condition is false we don't even have to check the second condition?

Or it equals to

```
if (list.length>2){
    if (list[3] == 2){
        ...
    }
}
```

?

And, what if it is written in C or python or some other languages?

Thanks

Comment: your 2 ways are equivalent

Comment: Java follows http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation (Short circuit evaluation) to validate that expression

Comment: Short circuit evaluation lets you evaluate conditions that will only be legal as long as the first condition is legal. You will often see code like  `if(string != null && string.length > 5)`

Comment: @RicardoCacheira actually they're quite different. Look at the first answer.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

It is common for languages (Java and Python are among them) to evaluate the first argument of a logical `AND` and finish evaluation of the statement if the first argument is `false`. This is because:

From [The Order of Evaluation of Logic Operators](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/46.html),

> When Java evaluates the expression d = b && c;, it first checks whether b is true. Here b is false, so b && c must be false regardless of whether c is or is not true, so Java doesn't bother checking the value of c.

This is known as [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), and is also referred to in the [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html).

It is common to see `list.count > 0 && list[0] == "Something"` to check a list element, if it exists.

---

It is also worth mentioning that `if (list.length>2 && list[3] == 2)` is *not* equal to the second case

```
if (list.length>2){
    if (list[3] == 2){
        ...
    }
}
```

if there is an `else` afterwards. The `else` will apply only to the `if` statement to which it is attached.

To demonstrate this gotcha:

```
if (x.kind.equals("Human")) {
    if (x.name.equals("Jordan")) {
        System.out.println("Hello Jordan!");
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("You are not a human!");
}
```

will work as expected, but

```
if (x.kind.equals("Human") && x.name.equals("Jordan")) {
    System.out.println("Hello Jordan!");
} else {
    System.out.println("You are not a human!");
}
```

will also tell any Human who isn't `Jordan` they are not human.

Comment: The last block is fair. Only `Jordan`s can run the world.

Comment: Bitwise operators of Python (`&`,`|`) **do not** support short circuiting. However the following operators of Python **do**:   `and`, `or`, `any`, `all`

Answer (score 27):

Yes. If the first condition is not satisfied then the remainder are not evaluated. This is known as *short-circuiting*. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) for more details. Note that this isn't particular to Java and lot of other languages will do the same.

Answer (score 19):

Right from the javadoc:

> The Conditional Operators
>
> The && and || operators perform Conditional-AND and Conditional-OR
>   operations on two boolean expressions. These operators exhibit
>   "short-circuiting" behavior, which means that the second operand is
>   evaluated only if needed.
>
> && Conditional-AND || Conditional-OR

Comment: flawless answer ! Plus one for short-circuiting concept!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, both usages are semantically equivalent... 
That is, unless the length is > 2, then is the code allowed to access more than the 2nd element.

In the first case, what matters is the `&&` operator, think of it as:
If first condition is true *then* apply second condition.

The subsequent condition also has an implicit "then" clause

```
if length greater than two
 then access third element
```

Answer (score 3):

If first condition is false then it wont check for second condition as anything && F =F
again it depends which bit wise operation you are doing .
like in case of OR (||) if first condition is true (T) the it wont check for second condition as anything || T = T but if its false (F) then it will definitely check for second

Answer (score 3):

You have specified in your IF statement that both of the conditions should be true for the System.out.println to be executed. So if the first condition itself fails,the second condition is not checked (this is for AND operator). But the second condition will be cheked if you have specified OR operator in the If statement.

Answer (score 0):

it will not read full expression because the result is clear even before the complete evaluation of the expression, and the result is returned