# Trying to understand code block combining Boolean and logical operators in java

Tags: java, boolean, logical-operators

Studying Java and this is a sample question I came across. I think I understand the logic behind the answer but could somebody confirm whether I am understanding it correctly?

```
public class Q8 {

    static boolean b1;
    static boolean b2;
    static boolean b3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean trueOrFalse = (b1 = true) || (b2 = true) && (b3 = true); //Line 9
        System.out.println(b1 + ", " + b2 + ", " + b3);
    }
}
```

Program prints `true, false, false` to console.

I understand that the class variables are assigned default values of false.

Am I right in saying that because `b1 = true` is assigning a value of true to `b1` instead of testing for equality like the question is laid out to have you believe, the or operator shortcuts leaving `b2` and `b3` as their default values and that's why `true, false, false` prints to the console?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two conditions in one if statement does the second matter if the first is false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606021/two-conditions-in-one-if-statement-does-the-second-matter-if-the-first-is-false)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is correct. You will set b1, evaluate and shortcut - so the rest is not set/evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

(b1 = true) assigns true to b1, and then the rest is skipped due to the OR operator ||, so b2 and b3 remain with their default false values

Answer (score -2):

Basically your code is a little bit different then how you as a human would read it. The compilers makes a few lines from your one line.

```
// This is not exactly how it will be translated obviously, but this should make it a little bit more understandable for you.
if (trueOrFalse = (b1 = true))
else if (trueOrFalse = (b2 = true) && (b3 = true));
```

This means that b2 and b3 will always just be skipped

`||` this is the OR operator and only checks the second statement when the first statement is `false` When ever one of the sides of an OR operator is true, code will execute.