# How to check null on Object where List<Object> Object contains Object?

Tags: java, java-8

For Example:

```
public class HelpMetric {
    private String metricId;
    private String supportType;
    private RequestSupportVo requestSupport;
} 

public class RequestSupportVo {
    private String requestSupportId;
}

public List<HelpMetric> getHelpMetric(String metricId) {
List<PolHelpMetric> list =helpMetricMapper.hlpMetricListToPolHelpMetricVoList(all);
        list.forEach(x -> {
            if (x.getRequestSupport() != null) {
                if (x.getRequestSupport().getRequestSupportId() != null) {
}
}
}
```

How i can optimise this above codetwo if condition null check using Java 8

if (x.getRequestSupport() != null) {
if (x.getRequestSupport().getRequestSupportId() != null) {

Comment: Have you heard of `&&`?

Comment: yes but you know in this case  if (x.getRequestSupport() != null && x.getRequestSupport().getRequestSupportId() != null) {           }. if x.getRequestSupport().getRequestSupportId() it's (x.getRequestSupport()) value is null means we will get null pointer exceptions..so we can't keep in && condition

Comment: Right. What's the problem? `&&` short-circuits if the first condition evaluates to false. You will not get a NullPointerException.

Comment: Yes,It will work.Thanks! something you can suggest how we can use stream and flatmap here to do this

Comment: You can use a stream with a filter if you really wanted to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two conditions in one if statement does the second matter if the first is false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606021/two-conditions-in-one-if-statement-does-the-second-matter-if-the-first-is-false)

Comment: if you want to do the conditions using the stream api, then list.filter(1st cond).filter(2nd cond).forEach(...)

Answer (score 1):

Java's logical operators, like those in many other languages, exhibit [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) behavior.

So a conditional block like the following:

```
if (a.getB() != null) {
   if (a.getB().getC() != null) {
       // ...
   }
}
```

Can safely be rewritten as:

```
if (a.getB() != null && a.getB().getC() != null) {
   // ...
}
```

Due to the short-circuiting behavior, in case the first condition fails, the second condition will not be evaluated, and does not risk throwing a `NullPointerException`.